# Wake-on-Lan Protocol

Tags: sleep-wake, wake-on-lan

What kind of WoL protocol does OS X use?

Trying to explain. When I use OS X on my Mac Mini and it is going to sleep it wakes up automatically when receiving any packets (e.g. when I try to connect via SSH).

Now I'm using Debian Jessie on my Mac mini and when I run `ethtool -i eth0` I get

```
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
```

Which means only *magic packet activity* supported by card.

So are there any Linux drivers to wake up my Mac on receiving SSH access requests for example?

Comment: WoL really isn't an apple thing, neither are magic packets, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN Is the question actually "how do I configure Debian Jessie to Wake-on-LAN?"

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is not so fine but question is "how to enable WoL for ANY activity (not only magic packet) in Jessie on Mac mini".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac registers with a [Bonjour Sleep Proxy](http://stuartcheshire.org/sleepproxy/) when it goes to sleep. The Bonjour Sleep Proxy (BSP) can be an AppleTV, Apple router, or built into the ethernet stacks of recent Macs. The BSP will pretend to be the Mac and continue to advertise services. If another machine tries to connect to one of those advertised services, the BSP will send the magic packet to wake the Mac up.

One service which receives special attention is ssh, so if you attempt to ssh to a Mac which is asleep but registered with a BSP, the BSP will wake up the Mac.

In order to have this work on Linux, you would need a program on Linux that can register the linux box with the BSP when it goes to sleep. It looks like [SleepProxyClient](https://github.com/awein/SleepProxyClient) will do that:

> These scripts enables your Non-Apple server (or NAS) to save energy by
>   going to sleep if it's currently not in use. But it will be instantly
>   woken up again by the SleepProxyServer using Wake on Lan (WOL) if one
>   of it's services is requested. See
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy for more details.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan):

Quote:

> I found that I didn't want any of the Wake On LAN settings except Wake on "Magic Packet" (g). I only wanted my machine to turn on when I specifically told it to, not on unicast messages (u), broadcast messages (b) or multicast messages (m).

Instead of Wake on "Magic Packet" (g), you would want Wake on unicast messages (u).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Comment: I can't install `u` flag because ethernet card (or it's drivers) doesn't support it.